# pymodbus REPL keep DTR / RTS high

Tags: serial-port, read-eval-print-loop, pymodbus

I am using the pymodbus [interactive console](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/REPL.html) to interact with a serial device. The device is powered over the communication port itself, namely using the [DTR and RTS pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136202/how-can-rs-232-dtr-rts-pins-be-used-for-power). Thus, they both need to be set high.

The device is correctly powered when using client.connect, however it turns off whenever I try to read any register, probably because neither DTR nor RTS are kept high during the requests.

Is there any way to keep these two pins high using the interactive console? I only saw examples [using a script](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/33) rather than on the REPL.

So far, I am doing:

```
pymodbus.console serial --method rtu --port /dev/ttyUSB0/ --stopbits 2

client connect --> returns True. Device power LED is on.
client get_serial_settings -->
     "baudrate": 19200,
     "port": "/dev/ttyUSB0",
     "parity": "N",
     "stopbits": 2.0,
     "bytesize": 8,
     "read timeout": 1.0,
     "t1.5": 0.000859375,
     "t3.5": 0.002005
client read_holding_registers address=49 count=1
--> Error, no response received, Device power LED goes down
```

Comment: So, for example, add where your program source code is and what's wrong with it. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added the commands. It's a command call rather than a source code.

Comment: Probably there is no such function or control method. If you search the source code, you will go to this page, but it does not seem to control DTR or RTS. [pymodbus/pymodbus/client/asynchronous/factory/serial.py](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/de0cc3efffd25ffdf1e4db4511b7ea74e105f3dc/pymodbus/client/asynchronous/factory/serial.py), [twisted/src/twisted/internet/_win32serialport.py](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/1d439dd1d9c7d302641550a925705d479ea5457f/src/twisted/internet/_win32serialport.py)

Comment: There is client.socket.setRTS as indicated https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/issues/33, which uses the dependant library PySerial, but is seems there is no way to call it from the console. It works though if I call it from a Python script. https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/search?q=setRTS

Comment: If there is information that can be used as a clue, why not modify the necessary functions and use them?

Comment: I wrote now a Python script which uses setRTS to true, however the problem was that the device was not answering the requests and then pymodbus closed the connection automatically because of this error. When using gtkterm instead, which doesn't turn RTS to off even if there is no response, the device at least doesn't power down.